# Lavender subsitute for Grilled Eggplant Nicoise

Tags: substitutions, herbs

Is it okay to tear open some lavender tulsi herbal tea bags?

Comment: It would certainly be safe, but it might not taste very good.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ Why not?

Comment: Because it is old, dry, and flavor balanced to be tea.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ Are there any substitutes then?

Comment: See Jefromi's answer... but you have to ask yourself, what does kind of ingredient is something?  If it is a signature ingredient, then you cannot substitute for it without losing the identity of the dish; if it is not, then omitting it or substituting for it just doesn't matter.

Comment: @MarkE Just in case you didn't already know, tulsi is basil, so you'll be adding both basil and lavender if you use the tea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite often teas go through a fermentation process that changes and intensifies the flavors. Herbal teas often mix a dried but non-fermented main aromatic like lavender with some sort of green or black tea which is fermented. A good example of this is mint tea, which is generally dried mint mixed with green tea. I wouldn't use mint tea as a substitute for fresh mint, it's never going to work the same.

Ripping open a tea bag and sprinkling it on a tuna salad isn't likely to win you any awards when people start crunching into bitter dried leaves. To be honest it would be hard to think of a more effective way to ruin it. Just add some fresh basil leaves instead, or ask around where you can gather some fresh lavender, it grows all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly try it. I don't know if the tulsi flavor will be what you want or not, though.

I also don't think I've ever heard of eggplant niçoise with lavender (and couldn't find a recipe with it) so it's probably also fine without it if you don't think the flavor's going to be what you want.